# update sensitive column with dummy data SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a table that includes forename and surname that needs changing with random data but readable for testing purpose. So I created another table with random forenames and surnames in a different database. I would like to update the test database with the random forenames and surnames I created. Also I want to rearrange the names updated just in case so I don't want it to be updated in order if you understand what I mean.

I got this query

```
update DB1.table 
set Forename = (???? from DB2.table (Forename)??????)
where Forename is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @Id int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Id 
FROM DB1.dbo.table 
WHERE Forename is not null

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
        update DB1.dbo.table 
        set Forename = (select top(1) Forename from DB2.dbo.table order by newid())
        where Id = @id

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @id   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Will update each forename with from table1 with a random forename from table2

You could then do the same for surnames, which would jumble up the forename/surname from table  2, which I assume is what you mean by the last line...

Comment: What this did is it updated all the columns with the same name. So I got a duplicate of names for the full column now.

Comment: Sorry, yeah you will need to use a cursor, ive updated my answer, this assumes your table has a unique id column to loop around.

Comment: I got this error 
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int

Comment: NO I didn't sort it yet